# Node JS Synchronous database call

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js, async.js

I have a problem using Node JS when making synchronous calls.. Here's my problem:

I have the following code:

```
async.doWhilst(function(callback) {
    //some code
    callback();
}, function() {
    //make a database call and based on the results I should 
    //return true to continue looping or false to stop here
}, function(err) {
   //do some things when the loop finishes
})
```

The problem is when calling the database it is asynchronous call and the loop continues before even returning the proper value.

Thank you alot for your comments, I have solved the problem by move the database call to the loop code like this:

```
var results = []
async.doWhilst(function(callback) {
    //some code
    sequelize.query('some query').success(function(result) {
        results = result;
        callback();
    });
}, function() {
    //use the results variable that is fetched from the database
    //return true to continue looping or false to stop here
}, function(err) {
   //do some things when the loop finishes
})
```

Comment: The test function should be synchronous, it would be _really, really, really_ bad to try to introduce async code and some kind of wait loop in it

Comment: I tried to make it synchronous but I can't figure out how, the problem is the database call depends on a variable changes in the loop code

Comment: You can't make an async operation behave synchronously.  You just can't.  It doesn't have the same timing as a synchronous operation and cannot be made to.

Comment: Thank you a lot @JanAagaardMeier your comment gave me a hint to move the database call to the loop code.. I will right an answer to what I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by move the database call to the loop code like this:

```
var results = []
async.doWhilst(function(callback) {
    //some code
    sequelize.query('some query').success(function(result) {
        results = result;
        callback();
    });
}, function() {
    //use the results variable that is fetched from the database
    //return true to continue looping or false to stop here
}, function(err) {
   //do some things when the loop finishes
})
```

Comment: This is not a synchronous  Database call.

Answer (score 1):

You can have Sequelize return once the data has actually returned using this method:

```js
return sequelize
  .query("Database query here")
  .success(function(result) {
      //Do something with result here
      else {
          //Return error
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following can help:

```
(function iterate() {
   executeDatabaseCall(..., function(e,r) {
      if (...conditions to continue looping are verified...)
         iterate();
      else
         ...manage the end of loop...
   });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use sync call, you can use this library :

https://github.com/luciotato/waitfor

It'll permit you to make sync call using :

```
var syncDataReceived = wait.forMethod(collection,'insert',{data:toinsert});
```