# Sequelize synchronous find

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Can I do a synchronous `find()` with Sequelize? e.g.

```
const user = User.find({ id: 1 })
```

(This seems to just get a promise.)

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839320/node-js-synchronous-database-call

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin Koa/generators.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928452/execute-sequelize-queries-synchronously

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```
const user = yield User.find({ id });
```

It seems to work as expected.

Comment: In my case yield return Generator { suspended }, What is the way to enable this feature with Node.js 4? :)

Comment: Agree with @JuanDavid, I would love to know the answer to this.

Comment: @NobleUplift I was using Koa with generators I think. You should look up async/await where this is pretty easy and no generators or koa required. But I don't think Node 4 works.

Answer (score -1):

Sequelize its all based in promises , if you are facing a use case like auth , you probably want to add a layer to your application , like middleware in express , so before your application execute some action , you need to authenticate users ( auth middleware )  and then pass to the next function.

```
//Auth Middleware example
function(req,res,next){
  User.find({id:1)
  .then(function(user){
     req.user = user;
     next();
  })
  .catch(function(error){
     next(error)
   })
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm recommend using `await` syntax

```
const user = await User.findById(id);
```

Comment: this can only be used inside async function