# Sequelize synchronous ORM

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Hello I'm using sequelize and I would like to make a synchronous query, but this is made asynchronously and return an wrong response.
I have this code:

```
function(user) {
  var allow = false;
  return User.find({ where: { id: user.id},
    include: [{
      model: Plan,
      attributes: ['id', 'name']
    }]
  }).then(function(u) {
    if(!u) throw new Error("0 user not found");
    user = u.dataValues;
    var plan = user.plan.dataValues.name;
    else if (plan == "Premium") allow = true;
    console.log("allow", allow);
    return allow;
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log("error:::", error);
  });
}
```

And the `console.log('allow', allow);` is printing `true` but when I call the function, the function is returning `false`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39928452/execute-sequelize-queries-synchronously/43250120

Answer (score 1):

You can't make asynchronous code synchronous, so you're going to have to deal with the asynchronicity.

However, it's not *too* difficult, since your function is returning a promise already. You can use that to pass the `allow` variable to a caller:

```
yourFunction(user).then(function(allow) {
  console.log('allow', allow);
});
```

Comment: Umm thanks but, allow depends of the query... How can I wait for the response? because it is returning a different response of the query :/

Comment: @PabloAlejandro right now your code is already waiting for the response (and processing it to determine the value of `allow`). You can run other queries and handle their results in a similar way.

Answer (score -1):

I think the `return allow;` statement is the return value to function `function(u) {}` inside `.then()`, not the `function (user) {}`.

Furthermore, `User.find()` returns a promise. If you read about Promise, you will see there are some ways to deal with your problem.
Here is one:

```
var myFunc = function(user, callback) {
  var allow = false;
  User.find({ where: { id: user.id},
    include: [{
      model: Plan,
      attributes: ['id', 'name']
    }]
  }).then(function(u) {
    if(!u) throw new Error("0 user not found");
      user = u.dataValues;
      var plan = user.plan.dataValues.name;
    else if (plan == "Premium") allow = true;

    callback(null, allow);

  }).catch(function(error){
    callback(error);
  });
}
```

Then you can use this function:

```
myFunc(user, function (err, allow) {
  // Do not forget to handle error

  // `allow` now could be used here
  console.log(allow);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but It didn't work, I am usign [fflip](https://github.com/FredKSchott/fflip) and it return a wrong value, and I want to be able to make a query inside of the fflip function on the [criteria](https://github.com/FredKSchott/fflip#criteria) :c