# How can I use async/await at the top level?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I have been going over `async`/`await` and after going over several articles, I decided to test things myself. However, I can't seem to wrap my head around why this does not work:

```js
async function main() {  
    var value = await Promise.resolve('Hey there');
    console.log('inside: ' + value);
    return value;
}

var text = main();  
console.log('outside: ' + text);
```

The console outputs the following (node v8.6.0) :

> > outside: [object Promise]
>
> > inside: Hey there

Why does the log message inside the function execute afterwards? I thought the reason `async`/`await` was created was in order to perform synchronous execution using asynchronous tasks.

Is there a way could I use the value returned inside the function without using a `.then()` after `main()`?

Comment: No, only time machines can make asynchronous code synchronous. `await` is nothing but sugar for promise `then` syntax.

Comment: Why does main return a value? If it should, probably it's not entry point and needs to be called by another function (e.g. async IIFE).

Comment: @estus it was just a quick function name while I was testing things in node, not necessarily representative of a program's `main`

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is part of ES2017, not ES7 (ES2016)

Comment: For the interactive node shell (REPL), try `node --experimental-repl-await`.

Comment: I'm using Next.js, and this was helpful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339259/470749

Comment: @nomad For recent versions of node that’s no longer necessary. The repl supports top level await by default

Comment: use bun, it worked perfectly for me

Comment: @DzmitryLahoda It shouldn't. Without `await`, getting a `Promise` is expected behavior. I guess OP wants top-level `await` and to just add the `await` keyword before the invocation.

Comment: i used this wbich works with await in main body, no need to.worm with promice or await directly https://github.com/ComposableFi/composable/blob/main/code/xcvm/index.ts

Answer (score 582, accepted):

> I can't seem to wrap my head around why this does not work.

Because `main` returns a promise; all `async` functions do.

At the top level, you must either:

1. Use **top-level `await`** ([proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#top_level_await); ES2022, [broadly supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#browser_compatibility) in modern environments) that allows top-level use of `await` in a module.

   or
2. Use a top-level `async` function that never rejects (unless you want "unhandled rejection" errors).

   or
3. Use `then` and `catch`.

#### #1 top-level `await` in a module

You can use `await` at the top-level of a module. Your module won't finish loading until the promise you `await` settles (meaning any module waiting for your module to load won't finish loading until the promise settles). If the promise is rejected, your module will fail to load. Typically, top-level `await` is used in situations where your module won't be able to do its work until the promise is settled and won't be able to do it at all unless the promise is fulfilled, so that's fine:

```
const text = await main();
console.log(text);
```

If your module can continue to work even if the promise is rejected, you could wrap the top-level `await` in a `try`/`catch`:

```
// In a module, once the top-level `await` proposal lands
try {
    const text = await main();
    console.log(text);
} catch (e) {
    // Deal with the fact the chain failed
}
// `text` is not available here
```

when a module using top-level `await` is evaluated, it returns a promise to the module loader (like an `async` function does), which waits until that promise is settled before evaluating the bodies of any modules that depend on it.

You can't use `await` at the top level of a non-module script, only in modules.

#### #2 - Top-level `async` function that never rejects

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const text = await main();
        console.log(text);
    } catch (e) {
        // Deal with the fact the chain failed
    }
    // `text` is not available here
})();
// `text` is not available here, either, and code here is reached before the promise settles
// and before the code after `await` in the main function above runs
```

Notice the `catch`; you *must* handle promise rejections / async exceptions, since nothing else is going to; you have no caller to pass them on to (unlike with #1 above, where your "caller" is the module loader). If you prefer, you could do that on the result of calling it via the `catch` function (rather than `try`/`catch` syntax):

```
(async () => {
    const text = await main();
    console.log(text);
})().catch(e => {
    // Deal with the fact the chain failed
});
// `text` is not available here, and code here is reached before the promise settles
// and before the code after `await` in the main function above runs
```

...which is a bit more concise, though it somewhat mixes models (`async`/`await` and explicit promise callbacks), which I'd normally otherwise advise not to.

Or, of course, don't handle errors and just allow the "unhandled rejection" error.

#### #3 - `then` and `catch`

```
main()
    .then(text => {
        console.log(text);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // Deal with the fact the chain failed
    });
// `text` is not available here, and code here is reached before the promise settles
// and the handlers above run
```

The `catch` handler will be called if errors occur in the chain or in your `then` handler. (Be sure your `catch` handler doesn't throw errors, as nothing is registered to handle them.)

Or both arguments to `then`:

```
main().then(
    text => {
        console.log(text);
    },
    err => {
        // Deal with the fact the chain failed
    }
);
// `text` is not available here, and code here is reached before the promise settles
// and the handlers above run
```

Again notice we're registering a rejection handler. But in this form, be sure that *neither* of your `then` callbacks throws any errors, since nothing is registered to handle them.

Comment: Thinking of it as a promise explains now why the function returns immediately. I experimented with making a top-level anonymous async function and I get results that make sense now

Comment: @Felipe: Yes, `async`/`await` are syntactic sugar around promises (the good kind of sugar :-) ). You're not just *thinking* of it as returning a promise; it actually does. ([Details](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions-EvaluateBody).)

Comment: I don't think you should mix async and old `Promise.catch()`, it makes it harder to read the code. If you use async, you should also use regular try/catch.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - I showed both above, with the all-`async` option first. For the top-level function, I can see it either way (mostly because of two levels of indentation on the `async` version).

Comment: @Felipe - I've updated the answer now that the top-level `await` proposal has reached Stage 3. :-)

Comment: If you just want the error to be dumped to the console like in a normal `function`, then just put `console.error(e.stack)` in your `catch` block.

Comment: Top-level await is now stage 4. Not sure how wide spread support is yet as this is brand new syntax. Mainly thinking of older browser versions which tend to hang around a while. Webpack 5 knows about this syntax as does babel.

Comment: @wheredidthatnamecomefrom - Yep, that's why I edited the answer on March 9th to say ES2022 (the next snapshot spec). :-) It's universally supported in modern browsers and in Node.js; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await#browser_compatibility.

Answer (score 66):

## 2023 answer: you can now use top level await in all supported versions of node.js

Most of the answers above are a little out of date or very verbose, so here's a quick example for node 14 onwards.

### In JavaScript (not using typescript)

There's a separate TypeScript answer below.

Make a file called `runme.mjs`:

```
import { exec as oldExec } from "node:child_process";
import { promisify } from "node:util";
const exec = promisify(oldExec);
const log = console.log.bind(console);

// Top level await works now
const { stdout, stderr } = await exec("ls -la");
log("Output:\n", stdout);
log("\n\nErrors:\n", stderr);
```

Run `node runme.mjs`

```
Output:
 total 20
drwxr-xr-x  2 mike mike 4096 Aug 12 12:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 30 mike mike 4096 Aug 12 11:05 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  130 Aug 12 12:01 file.json
-rw-r--r--  1 mike mike  770 Aug 12 12:12 runme.mjs



Errors:
```

You don't need to set `type`: `module` in your `package.json` because `.mjs` files are assumed to be ESM.

### In TypeScript using `esrun`

In TypeScript, using `esrun`.

`esrun` is better than `ts-node`, `tsrun` and `tsx` because:

- esrun doesn't require package.json changes
- esrun doesn't require a tsconfig.json
- esrun doesn't ever say it doesn't know how to run ts files
- esrun doesn't require you to use .mts files
- esrun defaults to a current version of JavaScript

```
npm i esrun
```

Run just run the TS with `npx esrun file.ts`:

```
Output:
 total 128
drwxr-xr-x@  8 mikemaccana  staff    256 18 Jul 13:50 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 13 mikemaccana  staff    416 17 Jul 14:05 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikemaccana  staff     40 18 Jul 13:27 deleteme.ts
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikemaccana  staff    293 18 Jul 13:51 deletemetoo.ts
drwxr-xr-x@ 85 mikemaccana  staff   2720 18 Jul 13:51 node_modules
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikemaccana  staff  46952 18 Jul 13:51 package-lock.json
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikemaccana  staff    503 18 Jul 13:51 package.json
-rw-r--r--@  1 mikemaccana  staff   1788 18 Jul 13:48 utils.ts
```

> ⚠️ You don't need to set `type`: `module` in your `package.json` because `esrun` has smart defaults.

Comment: I'm using Next.js, and this was helpful for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68339259/470749

Comment: it doesn't work with things like this `console.log(await 'bar');` which is no bueno

Comment: make sure to use `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`.

Comment: @RyanNorooz it will worth without `"type": "module"` in `package.json`

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes it does. Try `console.log(await exec("ls -la"));` in the example above.

Comment: @RyanNorooz Yes, `*.mjs` has been in this answer, and mentioned twice, for the last five hundred and thirty one days. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68756418/123671

Comment: this answer is a bit misleading, top-level `await` only works if you are using *ES modules* (ie, `"type": "module"` on `package.json`), instead of *CommonJS* as explained [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html)

Comment: @Bersan that's not correct, you don't need `type: module` in `package.json`. All `.mjs` files are assumed to be in ESM. See your link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html#new-file-extensions Try it.

Comment: @mikemaccana I see. With the `.mts` extension it will assume always to be ESModule (for the typescript case)

Comment: @Bersan Indeed! However tools like `esrun` will happily run `.ts` files as ESM without requiring `package.json` to be modified.

Answer (score 38):

[Top-Level `await`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) has moved to <del>stage 3</del> stage 4 (see [namo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1391762)'s comment), so the answer to your question *How can I use async/await at the top level?* is to just use `await`:

```js
const text = await Promise.resolve('Hey there');
console.log('outside: ' + text)
```

Of if you want a `main()` function: add `await` to the call to `main()` :

```js
async function main() {
    var value = await Promise.resolve('Hey there');
    console.log('inside: ' + value);
    return value;
}

var text = await main();  
console.log('outside: ' + text)
```

## Compatibility

- [v8 since Oct 2019](https://v8.dev/features/top-level-await)

  - the REPL in [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/08/devtools-release-notes#await), Node.js and Safari web inspector
- [Node v13.3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585793/top-level-await-doesnt-work-in-the-latest-node-js/59585976#59585976) behind the flag `--harmony-top-level-await`
- [TypeScript 3.8+](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html) ([issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25988))
- [Deno since Oct 2019](https://deno.news/issues/deno-newsletter-35-v0-19-0-top-level-await-dialtls-201414)
- [Webpack@v5.0.0-alpha.15](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/9177#issuecomment-499191382)
- [Bun v1.0.0](https://bun.sh/docs/runtime/modules#top-level-await)

Comment: --harmony-top-level-await did not work for me I am in node 14

Comment: @QuintenCabo It's probably because you are not using ES modules. To ensure that Node is in module mode, add `"type": "module"` to `package.json`.

Comment: At May 25, 2021,
Status updated to Stage-4.

Answer (score 15):

To give some further info on top of current answers:

The contents of a `node.js` file are currently concatenated, in a string-like way, to form a function body.

For example if you have a file `test.js`:

```
// Amazing test file!
console.log('Test!');
```

Then `node.js` will secretly concatenate a function that looks like:

```
function(require, __dirname, ... perhaps more top-level properties) {
  // Amazing test file!
  console.log('Test!');
}
```

The major thing to note, is that the resulting function is NOT an async function. So you cannot use the term `await` directly inside of it!

But say you need to work with promises in this file, then there are two possible methods:

1. Don't use `await` *directly* inside the function
2. Don't use `await` at all

Option 1 requires us to create a new scope (and this scope can be `async`, because we have control over it):

```
// Amazing test file!
// Create a new async function (a new scope) and immediately call it!
(async () => {
  await new Promise(...);
  console.log('Test!');
})();
```

Option 2 requires us to use the object-oriented promise API (the less pretty but equally functional paradigm of working with promises)

```
// Amazing test file!
// Create some sort of promise...
let myPromise = new Promise(...);

// Now use the object-oriented API
myPromise.then(() => console.log('Test!'));
```

It would be interesting to see node add support for top-level `await`!

Comment: [Node added support for top-level await behind a flag in v13.3]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585793/top-level-await-doesnt-work-in-the-latest-node-js/59585976#59585976).

Answer (score 9):

You can now use top level await in [Node v13.3.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v13.3.0/)

```js
import axios from "axios";

const { data } = await axios.get("https://api.namefake.com/");
console.log(data);
```

run it with `--harmony-top-level-await` flag

`node --harmony-top-level-await index.js`

Comment: That release changelog doesn't mention anything about top-level await, and it seems [support for the flag started with v13.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59585793/top-level-await-doesnt-work-in-the-latest-node-js/59585976#59585976).

Comment: with node version 18/19,  I get `node: bad option: --harmony-top-level-await`, and also top level await doesn't work, very confusing, I thought this was pretty much a guaranteed new feature

Answer (score 6):

The actual solution to this problem is to approach it differently.

Probably your goal is some sort of initialization which typically happens at the top level of an application.

The solution is to ensure that there is only ever one single JavaScript statement at the top level of your application.  If you have only one statement at the top of your application, then you are free to use async/await at every other point everwhere (subject of course to normal syntax rules)

Put another way, wrap your entire top level in a function so that it is no longer the top level and that solves the question of how to run async/await at the top level of an application - you don't.

This is what the top level of your application should look like:

```
import {application} from './server'

application();
```

Comment: You are correct that my goal is initialization. Things such as database connections, data pulls etc.  In some cases it was necessary to get a user's data before proceeding with the rest of the application. Essentially you are proposing that `application()` be async?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that if there is only one JavaScript statement at the root of your application then your issue is gone - the top level statement as shown is not async. The problem is that it is not possible to use async at the top level - you can't get await to actually await at that level - therefore if there is only ever one statement at the top level then you have sidestepped that issue. Your initialization async code is now down in some imported code and therefore async will work just fine, and you can initialize everything at the start of your application.

Comment: CORRECTION - application IS an async function.

Comment: I'm not being clear sorry.  The point is that ordinarily, at the top level, an async function does not await.... JavaScript goes straight on to the next statement so you cannot be certain that your init code has completed. If there is only one single statement at the top of your application that that just does not matter.

Answer (score 6):

Other solutions were lacking some important details for POSIX compliance:

You need to ...

- Report a 0 exit status on success and non-zero on fail.
- Emit errors to `stderr` output stream.

This will ensure that your command line app correctly integrates with other command line tools in bash/zsh etc and even Windows powershell or cmd. For example, if you're using it as part of a sequence of apps connected via a pipeline shell operator `|` then writing errors to `stderr` ensures that errors are visible (not piped into the next command). Only `stdout` should be streamed as `stdin` into the next command in your pipeline.  Returning a POSIX compliant exit status means you can correctly chain your Node app with other commands using `&&` or `||` shell operators.

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

async function main() {
 // ... await stuff ... 
}

// POSIX compliant apps should report an exit status
main()
  .then(() => {
    process.exit(0);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err); // Writes to stderr
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

If you're using a command line parser like [commander](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/), you may not need a `main()`.

Example:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

import commander from 'commander'

const program = new commander.Command();

program
  .version("0.0.1")
  .command("some-cmd")
  .arguments("<my-arg1>")
  .action(async (arg1: string) => {
    // run some async action
  });

program.parseAsync(process.argv)
  .then(() => {
    process.exit(0)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.message || err);
    if (err.stack) console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: The POSIX compliance is spot on!

Answer (score 5):

i like this clever syntax to do async work from an entrypoint

```js
void async function main() {
  await doSomeWork()
  await doMoreWork()
}()
```

Comment: Pretty syntax! I've never seen void used like that. If anyone's curious this explains why it works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void. Just throwing this out there: if you're just using a single async function or you don't care about the order multiple async functions execute in your can also use `void doSomeWork()`. Void essentially throws any returned value away and instead returns `undefined` instead

Comment: For just a simple test typescript project, this really helps since I don't have to make much config works in `tsconfig.json`. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

For Browser you need to add `type="module"`

without `type="module"`

```html
<script>
  const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  const users = await resp.json();
  console.log(users)
</script>
```

with `type="module"`

```html
<!--script type="module" src="await.js" -->
<script type="module">
  const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  const users = await resp.json();
  console.log(users)
</script>
```

Comment: To the point answer! I looked for a script that is "included" in html and not in a random JS file being imported.

Answer (score 3):

**Node** -
You can run `node --experimental-repl-await` while in the REPL. I'm not so sure about scripting.

**Deno** -
Deno already has it built in.

Answer (score 2):

Now with **ECMAScript22**, we can use `await` at the top-level module.

This is an example **with** ( `await` top-level ):

```
const response = await fetch("...");
console.log(response):
```

an other example **without** (`await` top-level )

```
  async function callApi() {
    const response = await fetch("...");
    console.log(response)      
}
callApi()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const resp = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
const users = await resp.json();
console.log(users)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to add type in package.json

   ```
   "type": "module"
   ```
2. You are good to go.

   ```
   import axios from 'axios';
   const res = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/wesbos');
   console.log(res.data);
   ```

Remember if you change type of document then you must have to write code in ES6 way.

Answer (score 1):

If your only goal is to control the execution order of asynchronous code mixed with other code for testing purposes, you could wrap the entire top-level code inside of an *immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE)* defined as an `async` function. In the example from the question, you would then add `await` before calling `main()`.

You can use this pattern when your code is not already in an `async` function or at the top level body of a module. In other words, if you're just testing a bunch of code inside of a js file and using tools like [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), [RunJs](https://runjs.app/), or any other type of JavaScript playground to watch the console window, wrap all of your code in an IIFE defined as `async` and use the `await` keyword when you want to wait for asynchronous code to finish before executing the next line.

```js
let topLevelIIFE = (async () => {  
  async function main() {  
      var value = await Promise.resolve('Hey there');
      console.log('inside: ' + value);
      return value;
  }

  var text = await main();  
  console.log('outside: ' + text);
  
})()
```

You would not need to use this pattern when running the code specified in the body of the IIFE inside of the REPL in Chrome DevTools or another browser REPL tool that behaves similarly.

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS 14.8+, you can use top-level await module (#3 solution). You can rename also .js to .mjs (ES module) instead of .js (.cjs CommonJS).

Answer (score 0):

const ABC = ()=>{
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
resolve()

})

ABC().then((res)=>{
// do something
})

}

Answer (score -7):

Since `main()` runs asynchronously it returns a promise. You have to get the result in `then()` method. And because `then()` returns promise too, you have to call `process.exit()` to end the program.

```
main()
   .then(
      (text) => { console.log('outside: ' + text) },
      (err)  => { console.log(err) }
   )
   .then(() => { process.exit() } )
```

Comment: Wrong. Once all promises have been accepted or rejected and no more code is running in the main thread, the process terminates by itself.

Comment: @Dev: normally you would like to pass different values to `exit()` to signal whether an error happened.

Comment: @9000 Yes, but that is not being done here, and since an exit code of 0 is the default there's no need to include it

Comment: @9000 in fact, the error handler should probably be using `process.exit(1)`