# Using "await" inside non-async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have an async function that runs by a setInterval somewhere in my code. This function updates some cache in regular intervals.

I also have a different, synchronous function which needs to retrieve values - preferably from the cache, yet if it's a cache-miss, then from the data origins 
(I realize making IO operations in a synchronous manner is ill-advised, but lets assume this is required in this case).

My problem is I'd like the synchronous function to be able to wait for a value from the async one, but it's not possible to use the `await` keyword inside a non-`async` function:

```
function syncFunc(key) {
    if (!(key in cache)) {
        await updateCacheForKey([key]);
    }
}

async function updateCacheForKey(keys) {
    // updates cache for given keys
    ...
}
```

Now, this can be easily circumvented by extracting the logic inside `updateCacheForKey` into a new synchronous function, and calling this new function from both existing functions.

My question is why absolutely prevent this use case in the first place? My only guess is that it has to do with "idiot-proofing", since in most cases, waiting on an async function from a synchronous one is wrong. But am I wrong to think it has its valid use cases at times?

(I think this is possible in C# as well by using `Task.Wait`, though I might be confusing things here).

Comment: If you are using `await` inside a function, the function *by definition* is asynchronous. Why not just add `async` to `syncFunc`? Or are you saying you want `syncFunc` to block the thread while it waits?

Comment: Not certain what issue is with existing code?

Comment: Yes, I'd like `syncFunc` to block

Comment: Im with you.  Every time I add an async call, I have to traverse up the stack and add await to its calling function, which requires adding async to the parent function, which requires adding await to *that* function, ad absurdium

Answer (score 101, accepted):

> My problem is I'd like the synchronous function to be able to wait for a value from the async one...

They can't, because:

1. JavaScript works on the basis of a "job queue" processed by a thread, where jobs have run-to-completion semantics, and
2. JavaScript doesn't really have asynchronous functions — even `async` functions are, under the covers, synchronous functions that return promises *(details below)*

The job queue (event loop) is conceptually quite simple: When something needs to be done (the initial execution of a script, an event handler callback, etc.), that work is put in the job queue. The thread servicing that job queue picks up the next pending job, runs it to completion, and then goes back for the next one. *(It's more complicated than that, of course, but that's sufficient for our purposes.)* So when a function gets called, it's called as part of the processing of a job, and jobs are always processed to completion before the next job can run.

Running to completion means that if the job called a function, that function has to return before the job is done. Jobs don't get suspended in the middle while the thread runs off to do something else. This makes code *dramatically* simpler to write correctly and reason about than if jobs could get suspended in the middle while something else happens. *(Again it's more complicated than that, but again that's sufficient for our purposes here.)*

So far so good. What's this about not really having asynchronous functions?!

Although we talk about "synchronous" vs. "asynchronous" functions, and even have an `async` keyword we can apply to functions, a function call is always *synchronous* in JavaScript. An `async` function is a function that *synchronously* returns a promise that the function's logic fulfills or rejects *later*, queuing callbacks the environment will call later.

Let's assume `updateCacheForKey` looks something like this:

```
async function updateCacheForKey(key) {
    const value = await fetch(/*...*/);
    cache[key] = value;
    return value;
}
```

What that's *really* doing, under the covers, is *(very roughly, not literally)* this:

```
function updateCacheForKey(key) {
    return fetch(/*...*/).then(result => {
        const value = result;
        cache[key] = value;
        return value;
    });
}
```

(I go into more detail on this in Chapter 9 of my recent book, [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://thenewtoys.dev).)

It asks the browser to start the process of fetching the data, and registers a callback with it (via `then`) for the browser to call when the data comes back, **and then it exits**, returning the promise from `then`. The data isn't fetched yet, but `updateCacheForKey` is done. It has returned. It did its work synchronously.

*Later*, when the fetch completes, the browser queues a job to call that promise callback; when that job is picked up from the queue, the callback gets called, and its return value is used to resolve the promise `then` returned.

> My question is why absolutely prevent this use case in the first place?

Let's see what that would look like:

1. The thread picks up a job and that job involves calling `syncFunc`, which calls `updateCacheForKey`. `updateCacheForKey` asks the browser to fetch the resource and returns its promise. Through the magic of this non-async `await`, we synchronously wait for that promise to be resolved, holding up the job.
2. At some point, the browser's network code finishes retrieving the resource and queues a job to call the promise callback we registered in `updateCacheForKey`.
3. Nothing happens, ever again. :-)

...because jobs have run-to-completion semantics, and the thread isn't allowed to pick up the next job until it completes the previous one. The thread isn't allowed to suspend the job that called `syncFunc` in the middle so it can go process the job that would resolve the promise.

That seems arbitrary, but again, the reason for it is that it makes it dramatically easier to write correct code and reason about what the code is doing.

But it does mean that a "synchronous" function can't wait for an "asynchronous" function to complete.

There's a **lot** of hand-waving of details and such above. If you want to get into the nitty-gritty of it, you can delve into the spec. Pack lots of provisions and warm clothes, you'll be some time. :-)

- [Jobs and Job Queues](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-jobs-and-job-queues)
- [Execution Contexts](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-execution-contexts)
- [Realms](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-code-realms) and [Agents](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-agents)

Comment: I understand there's only a single thread, but why not let the code author decide whether they'd like to hog it or not? Again, as I mentioned, my problem is easy to circumvent, I'm simply asking why it's explicitly forbidden in the first place.

Comment: @crogs: Because they can't hog it. For the async operation to complete, it has to receive an event, which means that a job has to be queued to call the event handler and then that job has to be picked up from the job queue. It can't do that if the job running your synchronous function is blocked, because you can't run two jobs at the same time in the same environment (even if one of them is blocked).

Comment: What would then happen if syncFunc is calling updateCacheForKey? Would it just continue executing the statements below the async function call since it can't suspend the job?
Btw thanks for your good answer!

Comment: @ErebosM - Yes, that's right. If it wants to see the result of `updateCacheForKey`, it needs to use `then` on the promise it returns. (`async` functions return promises.)

Comment: Damn! This is the wrong answer!  (But it clearly explains why I can't do what I want to do.)

Answer (score 58):

You can call an async function from within a *non*-async function via an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
(async () => await updateCacheForKey([key]))();
```

And as applied to your example:

```
function syncFunc(key) {
   if (!(key in cache)) {
      (async () => await updateCacheForKey([key]))();
   }
}

async function updateCacheForKey(keys) {
   // updates cache for given keys
   ...
}
```

Comment: Also see [How can I use async/await at the top level?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46515764/1497596).

Comment: This doesn't seem to wait until the function finishes!
https://codesandbox.io/s/t6cwg?file=/index.ts

Comment: @Ayyappa it is your mistake.you put logging after promise is done. what you expect?

Comment: Hey, the code is proper. Its supposed to execute the async function and print the log. Thats what the answer is about and it doesn't seem to work. Please let me know if i'm wrong.

Comment: This just creates another async function and puts the `await` in there, then calls the outer async function without `await`. So the outer function will run till it reaches the `await` then return control to `syncFunc`. Then everything after `await` will get run after `syncFunc` finishes. You could have achieved something similar just by calling `updateCacheForKey` directly from `runSync`.

Comment: I've downvoted, as this is misleading without more explanation: `updateCacheForKey()` is not immediately invoked if it actually does anything async. In that case all that happens *immediately* is that a Promise is created (to be executed later). *However* if updateCacheForKey() is genuinely sync, not returning Promise or doing an await, then it will immediately invoke it. In that case this is quite a cool hack for getting round the restriction that only an `async` function can use `await`. (BTW, the called function can be sync sometimes and async sometimes!)

Comment: @MatthiasFripp You couldn't achieve the same thing by just calling updateCacheForKey() directly, as a function must be marked `async` to be allowed to use `await`. So this hack bypasses that syntax error.

Comment: I expanded my comment into an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70317368/841830

Comment: The function updateCacheForKey, that we want to await on is supposed to do something async. Even though the actual code for updateCacheForKey might be sync for now, but in future someone might add an async piece code inside the function and things will start to break. This hack is good, but I believe it will cause more problems in future.

Comment: This hack solves 0 problems whatsoever at all period. You are still creating a hanging promise it's just wrapped in another async function. You could put the async function outside of this instead of in an IIFE then call it without await and you would obviously have the same problem as before. Making it an IIFE doesn't help the problem whatsoever. Not sure how this got so many upvotes but it is completely wrong

Comment: I agree with @Zachiah, this doesn't fit the original question's requirements ("I'd like the synchronous function to be able to wait for a value from the async one") and it is misleading because it makes the casual reader think the problem is solved when it isn't!

Answer (score 7):

This shows how a function can be both sync and async, and how the Immediately Invoked Function Expression idiom is only *immediate* if the path through the function being called does synchronous things.

```
function test() {
    console.log('Test before');
    (async () => await print(0.3))();
    console.log('Test between');
    (async () => await print(0.7))();
    console.log('Test after');
}

async function print(v) {
    if(v<0.5)await sleep(5000);
    else console.log('No sleep')
    console.log(`Printing ${v}`);
}

function sleep(ms : number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

test();
```

(Based off of [Ayyappa's code](https://codesandbox.io/s/t6cwg?file=/index.ts) in a comment to another answer.)

The console.log looks like this:

```
16:53:00.804 Test before
16:53:00.804 Test between
16:53:00.804 No sleep
16:53:00.805 Printing 0.7
16:53:00.805 Test after
16:53:05.805 Printing 0.3
```

If you change the 0.7 to 0.4 everything runs async:

```
17:05:14.185 Test before
17:05:14.186 Test between
17:05:14.186 Test after
17:05:19.186 Printing 0.3
17:05:19.187 Printing 0.4
```

And if you change both numbers to be over 0.5, everything runs sync, and no promises get created at all:

```
17:06:56.504 Test before
17:06:56.504 No sleep
17:06:56.505 Printing 0.6
17:06:56.505 Test between
17:06:56.505 No sleep
17:06:56.505 Printing 0.7
17:06:56.505 Test after
```

This does suggest an answer to the original question, though. You could have a function like this (disclaimer: untested nodeJS code):

```
const cache = {}

async getData(key, forceSync){
if(cache.hasOwnProperty(key))return cache[key]  //Runs sync

if(forceSync){  //Runs sync
  const value = fs.readFileSync(`${key}.txt`)
  cache[key] = value
  return value
  }

//If we reach here, the code will run async
const value = await fsPromises.readFile(`${key}.txt`)
cache[key] = value
return value
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Now, this can be easily circumvented by extracting the logic inside updateCacheForKey into a new synchronous function, and calling this new function from both existing functions.

[T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227878/906444) explains the semantics of async functions in JavaScript perfectly. But in my opinion the paragraph above deserves more discussion. Depending on what `updateCacheForKey` does, it may not be possible to extract its logic into a synchronous function because, in JavaScript, some things can only be done asynchronously. For example there is no way to perform a network request and wait for its response synchronously. If `updateCacheForKey` relies on a server response, it can't be turned into a synchronous function.

It was true even before the advent of asynchronous functions and promises: `XMLHttpRequest`, for instance, gets a callback and calls it when the response is ready. There's no way of obtaining a response synchronously. Promises are just an abstraction layer on callbacks and asynchronous functions are just an abstraction layer on promises.

Now this *could have been* done differently. And it *is* in some environments:

- In **PHP**, pretty much everything is synchronous. You send a request with curl and your script blocks until it gets a response.
- **Node.js** has synchronous versions of its file system calls (`readFileSync`, `writeFileSync` etc.) which block until the operation completes.
- Even plain old browser JavaScript has **`alert`** and friends (`confirm`, `prompt`) which block until the user dismisses the modal dialog.

This demonstrates that the designers of the JavaScript language *could have* opted for synchronous versions of `XMLHttpRequest`, `fetch` etc. Why didn't they?

> [W]hy absolutely prevent this use case in the first place?

This is a design decision.

`alert`, for instance, prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the page because JavaScript is single threaded and the one and only thread of execution is blocked until the `alert` call completes. Therefore there's no way to execute event handlers, which means no way to become interactive. If there was a `syncFetch` function, it would block the user from doing anything until the network request completes, which can potentially take minutes, even hours or days.

This is clearly against the nature of the interactive environment we call the "web". `alert` was a mistake in retrospect and it should not be used except under very few circumstances.

The only alternative would be to allow multithreading in JavaScript which is notoriously difficult to write correct programs with. Are you having trouble wrapping your head around asynchronous functions? Try semaphores!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add a good old .then() to the async function and it will work.

Should consider though instead of doing that, changing your current regular function to async one, and all the way up the call stack until returned promise is not needed, i.e. there's no work to be done with the value returned from async function. In which case it actually CAN be called from a synchronous one.