# A weird thing with async functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
$ cat x.js
async function print() {
    console.log("abc");
}

print();
$ nodejs x.js
abc
```

How can it be?! `print()` returns a `Promise` object that isn't awaited, is it? If it is not awaited, then why is the `console.log` executed?

Comment: Well, it should've printed your `console.log` since you execute it, then return a `Promise` object, which should have `fulfilled` to `undefined`. How is that weird?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47227550/using-await-inside-non-async-function

Comment: @choz The weird thing is that `abc` is indeed printed.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman It doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say that an empty function itself, returns `undefined` (Which actually doesn't return anything). Take a look at the sample below;

```
function print() {}
var returnVal = print(); // undefined
```

You'll notice that `returnVal` is `undefined`.

Now, if we have something in the `body` of `test()` there, but you still don't pass any return value, then `returnVal` will still be `undefined`.

```
function print() {
    console.log('abc');
}
var returnVal = print(); // undefined
```

So, in order for a function to have a return value, one simply just needs to `return` it.

```
function print() {
    console.log('abc');
    return 1;
}
var returnVal = print(); // 1
```

When you conver it to async function. Quoting from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

> 1. The body of an async function can be thought of as being split by zero
>    or more await expressions. Top-level code, up to and including the
>    first await expression (if there is one), is run synchronously. In
>    this way, an async function without an await expression will run
>    synchronously. If there is an await expression inside the function
>    body, **however, the async function will always complete asynchronously.**
> 2. Code after each await expression can be thought of as existing in a
>    .then callback. **In this way a promise chain is progressively
>    constructed with each reentrant step through the function**. The return
>    value forms the final link in the chain.

Now, based on the information above, here's what we know that refer to your question;

1. Your `print()` does not return anything, which should be `undefined`
2. The async function will complete asynchronously, meaning it will always return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Either **pending**, **fulfilled** or **rejected**

So, to say it in your question, here's what your function actually does;

```
async function print() {
    console.log("abc"); // Prints 'abc'
}

// Function above is equivalent to;

function printEquivalentInNonAsync() {
    console.log("abc"); // Prints 'abc'
}

var returnVal = print(); // `returnVal` is `undefined`
```

And, to answer your question

> If it is not awaited, then why is the console.log executed?

Regardless the async function is awaited, it still **executes!** - [Awaits just to ensure the line execution is halted until the Asynchronous function (Promise) has reached **fulfilled** or **rejected**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await). Note that, the first state of a Promise is **pending**.

Comment: When is a non-awaited async function executed? What if I have `f()` without `await` where `f` is an async function in a sync function?

Comment: If you use `await` to call your async function, it will return the resolved value instead of a promise, which is `undefined` in your case. If you don't use `await` as you are now, then it'll return `Promise<undefined>`

Answer (score 2):

yeah, like choz said ,async functions returns a promise, even if you haven't defined a promise in your code.

i think this returned promise turns fulfilled after all promises in await statement get resolved.

i test it in the following code, it also returns promise, which only turns fulfilled after all promises go resolved(after 3000ms in this case):

```
async function print2() {
   await console.log("abc")
    await new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {res(33)},3000)
    })
    await new Promise((res, rej) => {
        setTimeout(() => {res(33)},50)
    })
}
```

Comment: "this returned promise turns fulfilled after all promises in await statement get resolved" - but there is no await statement!

Comment: sorry, my statement was not clear, i mean in async functions,returned promise get resolved after all promises in the function get resolved(include those promise declared through await key-word, you know `await 3` works like  `Promise.of(3)`).although i'm not very clear of the relation between the returned promise and other promises in above statement.