# how to make synchronous function stop and wait for asynchronous function to finish executing in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, async-await, wait

I don't know if it is possible, but I really want to force a normal function to **stop** and wait for a async function. Here is a simple example:

```js
function draw_a_cat(){
  draw_cat_body();

  // get_head_information is asynchronous, and I want to STOP execution and wait for it to get info we need in order to draw the cat.
  wait for get_head_information();

  draw_head();
  display_cat_name();

  return true;
}

cat_drawn_yet = draw_a_cat();
console.log("drawn")!
```

I am not actually working on drawing cats, but I need to know how to do this. I wan't `draw_a_cat` to wait for `get_head_information`, meaning `draw_cat` will not return until it has gotten the head information and drawn the head. The head won't be drawn until the head information has been obtained, so that we can draw the head correctly.

And, the `console.log` won't happen until the cat is fully drawn and `cat_drawn_yet == "true"`. `draw_a_cat` is not an async function, meaning it cannot just `await get_head_information()`.

I want the program to stop and wait for the async `get_head_information` before continuing normally. I know it sounds stupid to freeze everything else, waiting for `get_head_information`, but I need to do this in a more complicated project where it just makes sense.

Comment: Well does get_head_information return a promise? Is it async? You need to share that code

Comment: This is not possible - read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47227878/4800344

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I guess I will just have to use promises.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* work with the result from the `get_head_information` inside the `draw_a_cat` function without making it [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). However, you would not be able to get a meaningful return value from the `draw_a_cat` function.

Here is an example using the [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) method of Promises. The logging of the result "drawn" is moved inside the `draw_a_cat` function in the callback passed to the `then` method.
Note that if there are more statements after the call to `draw_a_cat`, they will be executed **before** the code in the `then` callback.

```js
const draw_cat_body = () => { };
const draw_head = () => { };
const display_cat_name = () => { };
const get_head_information = () => Promise.resolve('round and fluffy');

function draw_a_cat() {
  draw_cat_body();

  // can wait here
  get_head_information()
    .then(info => {
      // you can work with what get_head_information returned
      draw_head(info); // assuming drawing the head is synchronous
      display_cat_name();
      console.log("drawn");
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
// can NOT wait here
draw_a_cat();
```

Comment: How sad. I was wanting the ability to stop sync processes within asyncs for some other asyncs to have easier control, but I guess I can just use setInterval() if I really need to wait. Of course, usually we don't need to wait in some weird way and can just use promises.