# await Promise.all not waiting despite async wrapper

Tags: javascript, async-await

Even after reading several answers to similar questions  (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451715/why-is-my-async-function-returning-too-soon?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level)) I unfortunately still do not understand, why this code does not await the promises and hence logs  **['check2']** last after the other checkpoints.

This is a minimal example using code [from this guide](https://dev.to/afifsohaili/dealing-with-promises-in-an-array-with-async-await-5d7g).  In the original code I need to fetch some Information from different sources before my express server can start listening.

```js
console.log("check1");

const resolveInTwoSeconds = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("check2"), 2000);
  })
};
async function test() {
  const asyncFunctions = [
    resolveInTwoSeconds()
  ];
  const results = await Promise.all(asyncFunctions);
  console.log(results);

}
(async() => await test())();
console.log("check3");
```

EDIT:
Imagine "check3" to be a lot of code that is depended on the sideeffects of test().
Thus I want it to run **after check2** was printed.
However I am using await here so **I do not have to change or move "check3"**.

Comment: it should work as expected, and log check2 after 2 seconds

Comment: If you want `"check3"` to be logged last, you should add that statement _within_ the last async IIFE.

Comment: Can you describe you issue more, tested your code and works find in terms of Promise.all

Comment: @EugenSunic _"...why this code ... logs ['check2'] **last after the other checkpoints**."_ - Expected output: `check 1 -> check 2 -> check 3`. Actual output: `check1 -> check 3 -> check 2`

Comment: it seems to me that you have reworded the actual question @Andreas

Comment: @EugenSunic Please provide evidence for the "rewording" part! And the last edit from OP supports my "rewording".

Comment: @Andreas sorry for that. you are right

Comment: `async` / `await` is just syntactic sugar for a Promise and `.then()`. Anything that isn't in the `.then()` call (in the function call after `await`) won't "wait".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line of code declares an `async` function and executes it:

```
(async() => await test())();
```

So far nothing waits for its result and the execution goes on to `console.log("check3")`.

You have to explicitly wait for it:

```
await (async () => await test())();
```

Now, this won't work yet, because the top-level function is not `async`. Whenever you need to call `await`, you have to make sure it's called inside an `async` function. One way to do this would be to wrap everything inside another `async` function:

```js
(async () => {
  console.log("check1");

  const resolveInTwoSeconds = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve("check2"), 2000);
    })
  };
  async function test() {
    const asyncFunctions = [
      resolveInTwoSeconds()
    ];
    const results = await Promise.all(asyncFunctions);
    console.log(results);

  }
  await (async ()=> await test())();
  console.log("check3");
})()
```

Otherwise, move your `check3` into an `async` function you already have, as others suggested.

Comment: Ok, thanks all. Meaning it's not possible without touching "check 3" (either moving it into the wrapper function or using a callback.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want. you need the `console.log` to be inside the async function.

```js
console.log("check1");

const resolveInTwoSeconds = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("check2"), 2000);
  })
};
async function test() {
  const asyncFunctions = [
    resolveInTwoSeconds()
  ];
  const results = await Promise.all(asyncFunctions);
  console.log(results);

}
(async() =>{ 
    await test();
    console.log("check3");
})();
```

Comment: move the code that supposed to be check3 into a function and call it after test, that's the only solution I can think of @Robin.