# JavaScript - Yield until next function is finished

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a simple Node.js app that has these methods in another file:

```
module.exports = {
  completeQuest(data) {
    // Code here
  },
  killMonster(data) {
    // Also code here
  },
};
```

And they are not AJAX commands. These just manipulate some data within the app. I'd export as such in `allActions.js`:

```
const player = require('./playerActions');

module.exports = {
  player,
};
```

and of course later, in main JS file `const actions = require('./allActions');`

So, generally, I'd do:

```
actions.player.killMonster();
actions.player.completeQuest();
```

But I want them to act one after the other. I know I can do `async/await`, but I'm not doing any AJAX calls, so would a `Promise` still be the best way?

What about using a `yield` function? Would that be good?

Comment: *"But I want them to act one after the other."* That's...how functions work. One runs to completion, then the next does. What are you seeing instead? We may need to know more about the implementation of the functions. You've said their "not ajax" which I assumed meant they didn't do asynchronous work, but then your question at the end suggests otherwise...

Comment: so, `completeQuest` and `killMonster` are async functions, right?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder You are right. I messed my wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `killMonster` and `completeQuest` perform asynchronous actions. (You've said they're "not ajax", but your question suggests they're not synchronous, either.)

Yes, this is a use case for [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), either explicit promises or those provided by [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). Have `killMonster` and `completeQuest` return a promise (either by doing so explicitly or making them `async` functions), and then either:

```
actions.player.killMonster()
.then(
    () => actions.player.completeQuest()
)
.catch(error => {
    // Handle error
});
```

or, within an `async` function:

```
try {
    await actions.player.killMonster();
    await actions.player.completeQuest();
} catch (error) {
    // Handle error
}
```

Here's a simple `async`/`await` example using `setTimeout` to provide the asynchronous part:

```js
const delay = (ms, ...args) =>
  new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args);
  });

// Stand-ins for the actions
const player = {
  actions: {
    async killMonster() {
      await delay(500, "monster killed");
    },
    async completeQuest() {
      await delay(800, "quest complete");
    }
  }
};

// Top-leve async function (see my answer here:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level
(async () => {
  try {
    console.log("Killing monster...");
    await player.actions.killMonster();
    console.log("Monster killed; completing question...");
    await player.actions.killMonster();
    console.log("Quest complete");
  } catch (e) {
    // Deal with error (probably don't just dump it to the console like this does)
    console.error(e);
  }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks. IT seems like async/await is still best way to go even when no AJX is involved.