# Need to wait for promise result from top level code

Tags: javascript, promise

I have to make an async call to a 3rd party API and I want the code execution to wait for the response.

```
async function getOrderData(orderId) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var service = new APIservice();
    service.GetOrderData(oid, function (event) {
      if (event && event.hasErrors() == false) {
        resolve(event.result);
      } else {
        reject(null);
      }
    });
  });
}

var order = getOrderData(orderId);
//from here the code should only resume once the var order is defined with whatever's returned from the api
```

This is the top level code (not async) so I cannot use await.

EDIT:
Answering some suggestions:

```
this.$onInit = function () {
    this.order = "wrong value";
    getOrderData(orderId).then(order => {
        this.order = "correct value";
    });
};
```

this function will end with "test" being "wrong value". This is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you not wrap that code in an async function and await the response? We may need more context here.

Comment: What is `GetOrdersById`? I don't see that in your question at all.  If you meant `getOrderData` being `async` that doesn't matter, you want the function the code snippet posted is running in to be `async` so you can `await` the return response of `getOrderData`, as others have posted solutions of.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. "GetOrderData" is an async function (sorry for the typo)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use async/await at the top level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level)

Answer (score 3):

You can `await` the `Promise` returned by `getOrderData()`.

However, in order to use `await` you need to wrap your call to `getOrderData` in an `async` function (there is no such thing as top-level `await` at the moment - it *may* one day [be a thing](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) however. At present, it can only be used when inside an `async` function):

```
// getOrderData function initializaion...

(async _ => {
  var order = await getOrderData(orderId); // wait to recieve data before proceeding
  // You can now write code wih `order`
})().catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Alternatively, you can write your code in a `.then` callback (which `await` is simply just syntactic sugar for) from the returned `Promise` of `getOrderData()` like so:

```
// getOrderData function initializaion...

getOrderData(orderId).then(order => {
  // write code in here which relies on `order`
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});;
```

Comment: this.$onInit = function () {
                this.test = "wrong value";
                getOrderData(orderId).then(order => {
                    this.test = "correct value";
                });
            };

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this:

```js
async function the_whole_thing() {
  async function the_api_wrapper() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('joe!'), 10);
    });
  }
  
  let result = await the_api_wrapper();
  console.log(result);
}

the_whole_thing();
```

**Note #1**: I just swapped out the API you are calling with `setTimeout`, as it is also a function that takes a callback (similar to your case) and it also ensures stuff happen asynchronously.

**Note #2**: note that the `async/await` syntax can only be used in the body of another `async` function, so thats why I wrapped the whole thing, well, in `the_whole_thing`.

Comment: Sorry, I am missing the point. If I call "the_whole_thing" in the main thread will I not get the same result (thread ending before my var is defined)?

Comment: you will get the same result. but you cannot get the value in the main thread, at least not with a simple variable assignment. basically `x = f()` when `f` is an async function will not cause x to be the result of `f` but a `Promise` that can be used to fetch the result of `f` in an async manner. you can work around that by doing `x = await f()`, however you will not be able to do that in your main thread (or in the body of any function that is not async itself).

perhaps [this pen](https://codepen.io/lorean_victor/pen/WBBRvq) can help illustrate that difference better.