# How do I store a value from a petition?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I want to get a value from an API and save that value for later, but I'm having troubles.

I get the result I want when I use console.log(), but when I do exactly the same thing with "return()" I get this result:

Promise{< resolved >:"The value I want"}

I'll show you my code:

```
const getDataAA = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json")
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log("async/await based")
  console.log(data.USD.transferencia)
}
```

When I call getDataAA() I get what I want in the console, but I want to store that value in order to use it, so I changed "console.log(data.USD.transferencia)" for "return(data.USD.transferencia)".

Then I do something like this in order to save the value:

```
let dolarPrice = getDataAA()
```

Why when I use "console.log" I get the value but when I use "return" I get also the promise?

Comment: `async` functions always return a Promise.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a way to return only the value?

Comment: @BernardoAyala No. You are making an asynchronous IO operation, so you cannot have it return only the value. However, if you prefix your function call by `await`, your variable will have the value : `let dolarPrice = await getDataAA()`

Comment: Either `await` the function or use the Promise API.

Comment: Ok, I get it, now I understand what's happening, thank you for that. I tried to use "await" with the function as you told me and I get this error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

But I don't know why, the function is asyncrhonous.

Comment: @BernardoAyala I copy/pasted your code from your question, with the `await` call (like in my comment), and I got `async/await based` followed by `21402.71`. Make sure your actual code is the same as from your question.

Comment: Oh yes, I get that result in the console, too. But I'm having troubles saving that value. Did you write the let dolarPrice = await getDataAA() inside or outside the function?. Because when I write it inside I can't use that value again, the console says that "dolarPrice" is not define

Comment: I don't understand. Of course I called it outside the function, otherwise it would be recursive.

Comment: @Seblor Sorry for being so confusing but I'm new in JavaScript and everything is confusing to me xD. I asked because I'm getting this error when I call it outside the function:

Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function

I'm trying to understand why, but I don't get it, yet.

Comment: Ah, this is because the `await` keyword is not available at the top-level. the keywork can only be used in an `async` function. More information on that here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level. But good news ! the top-level await feature is a stage 3 proposal (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered I way to solve this! I defined a variable outside the function and then the function stored the value I wanted inside that variable. This is my code:

```
const getDataAA = async () => {
  const response = await fetch("https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json")
  const data = await response.json()
  console.log("async/await based")
  dolarPrice = (data.USD.transferencia)
}

let dolarPrice

getDataAA()
```

That way I stored the value inside the "dolarPrice" variable. Thanks all the people who answered my question, I found the solution thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

```
        const getDataAA = async () => {
          const response = await fetch("https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json")
          return response.json()
        }

        let response = await getDataAA();
        console.log(response);
```

-- EDITED

so this one another example how use it.

1. the async method (getDataAA) have to return something.
2. everytime you need to call an async method you have to use await (
   if you wait until it's completed)
3. everytime you use await the method must be async.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">

  var f = async () => {
   const getDataAA = async () => {
     const response = await fetch("https://s3.amazonaws.com/dolartoday/data.json")
     return response.json()
   }

   let response = await getDataAA();
   console.log(response);
  }
  f();
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did and how you solved OP's issue ? A good explanation can do much more than a code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that maybe something is wrong with my browser because I copy/pasted this exactly as you wrote it and I get this error :

Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function.

Comment: The async function ( getDataAA) needs to returns a value obviously, then everytime you need to call an async function ( and you want to wait it) you have to use await.

Comment: @RiccardoGai Thanks Ricardo, I copied your code, but I still don't understand how to store the value I want to use for other operations. With your code I get the response in the console, but I want to store a value inside a variable to use it later.

Comment: let response = await getDataAA(); with this the response is stored in a variable and you can use for any operations you want

Comment: @RiccardoGai But when I call that variable in the console it says that is not defined, I'm not able to use that value outside the function.