# Use async/await in a method of module.export

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I've a problem, I want to create a module that exports various call to db and use it with await in my app... here an example:

```js
// module
const config = require("../config/config");
const mysql = require("mysql2/promise");

const getUsersData = async (args) => {

  const db = await connectDb();

  let rows, fields;
  try {
    [ rows, fields ] = await db.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id !== ? LIMIT ?", [0, 10]);
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
  return rows;
};

const connectDb = async () => {
  const db = await mysql.createConnection({
    host: config.dbhost,
    user: config.dbuser,
    password: config.dbpassword,
    database: config.dbname,
  });

  return db;
};

module.exports = {getUsersData, connectDb}
```

In my app I want to have:

```js
const myModule = require("./db/lyDb");

let myData = await myModule.getUsersData({args: 'my argument'});
```

The problem is that I receive the following error `await is only valid in async function`

How to fix it? Tnx

Comment: Thank you to all, I's my fault, I forgot to use async keyword in my listener, but your answers has helped me to figure the problem:
```
socket.on("connection", async (_socket) => { .. })

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you wrap your main app code in an `async` function?

```
const myModule = require("./db/lyDb");

const main = async () => {
  let myData = await myModule.getUsersData({args: 'my argument'});
  // rest of your application
}

main()
```

Comment: OP can also use Top Level awaits based on if OP can use modules and has a ES2018 supporting Node.JS version

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
let myData = await myModule.getUsersData({args: 'my argument'});
```

must be executed from an **async** function.

i.e.

```
async function someFunc() {

    let myData = await myModule.getUsersData({args: 'my argument'});

}
someFunc();
```

Comment: There is no need in 2020 to execute awaits only from async functions especially with top level awaits

Answer (score 1):

Error is self explanatory, you cannot call await outside a async function. Either you should use then clause to access response or create a async function to use await.

```js
myModule.getUsersData({args: 'my argument'}).then(res => {
// do something
})
```

or

```js
const main = async () => {
    let myData = await myModule.getUsersData({args: 'my argument'});
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is that you are using a Top-Level Await

```js
const myModule = require("./db/lyDb");

let myData = await myModule.getUsersData({args: 'my argument'});
```

Await can only be called in an async function in the configuration you are possibly running Node.JS

To help you out, one way is to use

```js
const myModule = require("./db/lyDb");
(async () => {
   let myData = await myModule.getUsersData({args: 'my argument'});
})();
```

To actually, use Top-Level awaits, your JS must be a module and you must be targeting or running a Node.JS version which supports ES2018 with ESNext Module System

Also see [How can I use async/await at the top level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level)