# Not Found: NextAuth.js in Next13 App Level Directory

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth, next.js13

Hi Please anyone can help me? I'm using a package

```
"next": "13.2.4",
"next-auth": "^4.20.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
```

and I have submit function to register the user

```
 async function onSubmit(values: any) {
    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", },
      body: JSON.stringify(values),
    }

    await fetch('/api/auth/signup', options)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        if (data) router.push('/authentication');
      });
    console.log(values)

  }
```

but when I hit submit I got this error

**http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signup 404 (Not Found)**

Below is my project directory

[image]

Comment: API end-points should be declared inside the `pages` folder, so change your structure to `pages/api/auth`. Also, you should update `[...nextauth]` extension to `[...nextauth].ts`.

Comment: Also check your signup function, if there is something wrong it could cause 404 error

Comment: Nextjs 13 App Level Directory doesn't have Pages Directory anymore...

Answer (score 1):

the name of the file should be `route.ts` inside the directory. you are sending a request to `/api/auth/signup`. so you should have this folder structure

```
 -api
   -auth
     -signup
        -route.ts
```

Comment: Hi Yilmaz I got this error ```./node_modules/bson/lib/bson.mjs
Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
Error: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)```

Comment: btw I did this config as well but no chance.. **experiments.topLevelAwait: true**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68339243/how-can-i-use-top-level-await-in-typescript-next-js/68339259#68339259

Comment: @erwin somewhere in your codebase you are using `await` which is not inside an `async` function