# Aync / Await return pending

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise

Why is my Aync Await Function returning an Pending Promise ? i already tried `.then` statement but it doesn't work, here is my code :

```
  const findData = async () => {
    let query = await userSchema.findOne({ _id: research["uploaderID"] });
    return query;
  };

  research["uploaderInfo"] = findData();

  console.log(findData());
```

when i tried to console.log the findData, it just gave me this :

```
Promise { <pending> }
Promise { <pending> }
```

and when i tried to check the research object, it was empty, but when i tried to add a `console.log(query)` inside the `findData()` function, it gave me the expected result, which mean the `query` is correct, and this is an issue because of the async / await.

**UPDATE**

i tried @dai solution to add await when i tried to set my research like this

```
  const findData = async () => {
    let query = await userSchema.findOne({ _id: research["uploaderID"] });
    return query;
  };

  async () => {
    research["uploaderInfo"] = await findData();
  };
```

when i tried this, any code that i put inside the second nameless `async function` does not work, i tried to set the `object` to random `string` and it still doesn't changing

Comment: Your `findData` function is an `async` function, which implicitly always returns a `Promise`, which means you need to `await` its returned `Promise` like so: `research["uploaderInfo"] = await findData();`

Comment: Yes, Agree with @Dai, Please Put await so you will get your answer.

Comment: it tells me that i need to put await inside an async function, do i need to put it inside a function ? @Dai

Comment: @Walls What version of NodeJS are you running? "top-level `await`" should be supported by modern versions of NodeJS AFAIK. Otherwise, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level

Comment: What do you mean any code you put inside the second async function does not work? Are you invoking that function?

Comment: @user16708140 inside the second async function, i tried to change the object value with the `findData()` using the `await`, but the data is not changing

Comment: @Dai im running the 14.17.xxx version of node that is reccomended for most users

Comment: But are you calling the second function? In here is just a function declaration

Comment: Where are you getting the `research` and `userSchema` objects from? Please post **all** your code (but keep "all code" to the bare minimum needed to reproduce the issue)

Answer (score 1):

Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56590390/159145

**Short answer**: Run NodeJS 14.17 (or any version after 13.3+) with the flag `--harmony-top-level-await` and you can have this:

```js
// program.js

const findData = async () => {
    let query = await userSchema.findOne({ _id: research["uploaderID"] });
    return query;
};

research["uploaderInfo"] = await findData();

console.log(research["uploaderInfo"]);
```

...or even just this (assuming your `research` and `userSchema` objects are trivially instantiated):

```js
// program.js

research["uploaderInfo"] = await userSchema.findOne({ _id: research["uploaderID"] });

console.log(research["uploaderInfo"]);
```

---

**Longer answer without NodeJS flags**:

It looks like NodeJS 14.17 doesn't yet support "top-level `await`" (someone correct me if I'm wrong) but that's not a *real* problem: it just means you need to wrap all of your original top-level ("root function") code in an `async` function and invoke it immediately.

Like so (I've named the function `entrypoint`, though you can use an anonymous function if you like):

```js
// program.js

async function entrypoint() {
    
    const research   = ...
    const userSchema = ...

    const findData = async () => {
        let query = await userSchema.findOne({ _id: research["uploaderID"] });
        return query;
    };
    
    research["uploaderInfo"] = await findData();

    console.log(research["uploaderInfo"]);
}

entrypoint();
```

---

Note that you can elide and inline `findData`'s function and call `userSchema.findOne` directly:

```js
// program.js

async function entrypoint() {

    const research   = ...
    const userSchema = ...    

    research["uploaderInfo"] = await await userSchema.findOne({ _id: research["uploaderID"] });

    console.log(research["uploaderInfo"]);
}

entrypoint();
```