# Using node-fetch in js file in browser and in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I have built a class to do some fetch from an API and construct a suited response for my app.

I use this file both in an app that run on the browser, and on a CLI app to work on the terminal.

As I built the browser app first, there was no import to node-fetch.
Now when I try to use this .js file in my CLI app, it returns error saying `fetch is not defined`.

If I add to my api client .js file: `import fetch from "node-fetch"` then now my browser app is not working as well, print to the console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "node-fetch". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

Is there anyway to apply fetch and use the same file for both?

Thanks

Comment: The readme has links for cross env fetch..... https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-unfetch + https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch

Comment: Use Node.js 16 or higher as it has built-in support for fetch api

Answer (score 2):

For use-cases where you cannot update Node, you can conditionally import the Fetch API.

```
let fetch = globalThis?.fetch;

if (!fetch && process?.versions?.node) {
  fetch = (await import('node-fetch')).default;
}

console.log(fetch);
```

Note that this uses [top-level await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level).

Answer (score 1):

Your options are:

- Use Node.js 18 or newer which has [native support for `fetch`](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/announcements/v18-release-announce/)
- Use a tool like Webpack which can [pick different versions of `fetch` depending on the target environment](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-bundle-your-library-for-both-nodejs-and-browser-with-webpack-3584ec8197eb).

The former option is much easier (at least from a technical POV)!

Answer (score 1):

When using NodeJS, fetch is not an actual thing. I'd definitely replace that with the Axios module as shown below:

```
const axios = require('axios');

axios.get(link).then(response => {
  // ...
});
```