# How to assign axios respond to variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, top-level-await

In Nodejs v16.15.1, I can easily assign axios respond to a variable.

```
const clientlist = await axios.get('http://test.lab/api/getclients');
```

However, when I upgraded to latest Nodejs v19.6.0,
I keep getting error: *await is only valid in async functions*.

So, I tried to change the code as per below

```
var uid1 = 0;

async function getUID() {
  let res = await axios.get('http://test.lab/api/?user=test');
  let data = res.data;
  return data;
}

// Call start
(async() => {
  console.log('before start, the value is '+ uid1);

  uid1 = await getUID1();
  
  console.log('after start, the value is '+ uid1);
})();

//trying to use uid1 for the rest of the code

console.log('outside async, the value is '+ uid1);

// returned empty
```

However, I can only use axios respond within the async scope.
I cannot use it outside.

What can I do to make it work like it did in nodejs v16?

Comment: "*I can only use axios respond within the async scope*" - yes, and that's by design: you need to wait for it. Just put all the code that needs the response inside that scope.

Comment: @Bergi — The question is about Node.js support for top-level await. The detour into the IIFE seems to be a distraction from the main point. I don't think the duplicate choice is a good one.

Comment: @Quentin Oh, I missed the first sentence I guess. I wonder though what might have changed to make nodejs no longer treat the file as a module?

Comment: @Bergi — I think the OP just started a new project and didn't realise there was a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js still supports top-level await, but (still) only in [ECMAScript modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) (i.e. not in the default, [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), modules).

To make Node.js recognise the file as an ECMAScript module, either:

- Add `"type": "module"` to your *package.json* file and continue using a `.js` file extension.
- Rename the file to have a `.mjs` file extension

---

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) covers why your attempted workaround (with an IIFE) failed.

Comment: I managed to solved this problem by converting the file extension from .js to .mjs.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level