# Node.js file loading difference between .load and cli arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a simple server in vanilla JavaScript and Node.js. I made a `database.js` file which contains abstractions to interact with my database (redis).

I want to automatically set `n_users` and `n_rooms` if they are not yet found in the database. To do so, I have the following lines in `database.js`:

```
//set n_users if never set in redis
if (await getKey("n_users") == null){
    setKey("n_users", 0);
}
//set n_rooms if never set in redis
if (await getKey("n_rooms") == null){
    setKey("n_rooms", 0);
}
```

This code works as expected when I open a node session and then type `.load database.js`. However, the code does not work when directly calling `node database.js` from the terminal:

```
/Users/.../database.js:29
if (await getKey("n_users") == null){
          ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

I expected javascript files to work similarly to python files, in the sense that the entirety of a python file gets interpreted when called (or imported). I can't find any information on how exactly `node` handles its input files to correct what I'm doing wrong.

Ultimately, I want to be able to automatically execute the above lines of code when running `node server.js` from a terminal, where `server.js` requires an object from `database.js`. What is the best way to acomplish this?

### Edit

Here's my `database.js`file:

```
let User = require('./shared/user').User;
let Room = require('./shared/room').Room;
const md5 = require('./stack_md5').MD5;
const redis = require('redis');
const salt = require('./salt').salt;


var prefix = "JS2023:";
const client = redis.createClient();
client.connect();

//should be map of token to user_id
let TOKENS = {};

async function getKey(key) {
    return await client.get(`${prefix}${key}`);
}


async function setKey(key, value){
    await client.set(`${prefix}${key}`, value);
}

async function delKey(key){
    await client.del(`${prefix}${key}`);
}

//set n_users if never set in redis
if (await getKey("n_users") == null){
    setKey("n_users", 0);
}
//set n_rooms if never set in redis
if (await getKey("n_rooms") == null){
    setKey("n_rooms", 0);
}

//using local objects because mongodb doesnt work dont know why
const DB = {
    //user should have at least username and password
    //automatically md5's the password
    //TODO refactor for clarity
    create_user: async function(user_data){
        //username must be unique
        console.log(`user data: ${user_data}`);
        if (await DB.get_user_id_by_username(user_data.username) != undefined) return Promise.reject("Username is already taken!");

        let user_id = parseInt(await getKey(`n_users`));

        let username = user_data.username;
        let user_salt = salt(16);

        let password = md5(user_data.password + user_salt);

        let user = new User({id: user_id, username: username, password: password, salt: user_salt});

        let user_string = JSON.stringify(user);

        setKey(username, user_id)
            .then(DB.set_user_by_id(user_id, user_string))
            .then(setKey("n_users", user_id + 1));

        return user_id;
    },

    get_room_by_id: async function (id){

    },

    set_room_by_id: async function (id, room_string){

    },

    //TODO this returns undefined rn
    get_user_by_id: async function (id) {
        //access DB
        //clean data
        //call callback with data
        return await getKey(id);
    }, //TODO enforce unique usernames

    set_user_by_id: async function (id, user_string) {
        await setKey(id, user_string);
    }, //id should be unique

    get_user_id_by_username: async function (username) {
        return await getKey(username);
    }, //verify password is correct and return cool access token

    authenticate: async function (user_id, password) {
        let user = JSON.parse(await getKey(user_id));

        if (user.password !== md5(password + user.salt)) return Promise.reject("Wrong password!");

        //is user already is online, he is in tokens. will not be authenticated
        for (token in TOKENS) {
            if (TOKENS[token] === user_id) return Promise.reject("User is already connected!");
        }

        var user_token = await DB.token(32);
        //check that token is unique and if not create a new one and hope it is
        while (user_token in TOKENS) user_token = await DB.token(32);
        TOKENS[user_token] = user_id;

        console.log(`generated token for ${user_id}: ${user_token}`)

        return user_token;

    },

    //update_obj an object with the fields to update {username, password, whatever else except id and salt}
    update_user: async function (id, update_obj) {
        DB.get_user_by_id(id)
            .then(function (user) {
                for (let field in update_obj) {
                    switch (field) {
                        //password stored as its hash
                        case "password":
                            //salt is stored by user
                            user[field] = md5(update_obj[field] + user.salt);
                            break;
                        //id is only given by the server and cannot be modified
                        case "id":
                            continue;
                        case "salt":
                            continue;
                        //update inverse key-value in redis db
                        case "username":
                            delKey(`${user[field]}`)
                                .then(setKey(`${id}`, update_obj[field]));
                            break;
                        default:
                            user[field] = update_obj[field];
                    }
                }
                return user;
            }).then(user => DB.set_user_by_id(id, JSON.stringify(user)));
    },

    //make a random token of given length
    token: function (length) {
        return salt(length);
    },

    // delete token associated with user_id (i.e, user no longer online)
    revoke: async function (user_id) {
        for (token in TOKENS) {
            if (TOKENS[token] == user_id) {
                delete (TOKENS[token]);
                console.log(`${token} revoked, user ${user_id} is no longer online.`);
            }
        }
        //for chaining promises
        return user_id;
    }, // this doesn't need to be async since tokens have to be dynamically maintained

    /**
     * check if token string is in tokens map
     * @param token
     * @returns {boolean}
     */
    present: function (token) {
        for (let stored_token in TOKENS) {
            if (token === stored_token) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    },


}

module.exports = {DB, TOKENS};
```

Comment: FYI, checking and setting a database value in two separate database operations like you show is a race condition waiting to happen.

Comment: I think we would have to seed the structure/code of your database.js file to understand why it won't run on its own.  Typically a file is either designed to run on its own or to be a module that someone else loads.  It sounds like you're trying to make one file do both which is a bit odd.  So, please show the actual code of the file.  Nodejs does interpret or run the entire file when it is imported.  A file designed to be a reusable module that other files load will typically then initialize itself and export something that others can use.

Comment: One thing that might be confusing you is that each file in nodejs is a separate scope.  Symbols created in one file and not automatically available to other files.  You don't show where `getKey()` is supposed to come from, but if `database.js` doesn't define that function itself, then it will have to import something to get access to that function.  Again, please show the actual code of `database.js` for us to be able to help.

Comment: @jfriend00 maybe it is odd, I was mainly relying on how python works to execute those lines when the module got loaded. I can post the full code in an edit if it helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use async/await at the top level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level)

Comment: @derpirscher not really, node just does not want to run the code unless using the .load command. Thanks for the help though

Comment: because you have a toplevel await ... just as the answer you accepted told you ... and the linked answer also tells you how to run such a file ...

Comment: @derpirscher you are right, I understood the link you posted answered a different problem. I've tried one of the solutions listed and the code runs now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement in your file:

```
//set n_users if never set in redis
if (await getKey("n_users") == null){
    setKey("n_users", 0);
}
```

is attempting to use what is referred to as "top level await" (an `await` statement at the top level scope of a module).  That is only supported in recent versions of nodejs in ESM module files.  Your module is a CommonJS module and thus you can't use top level `await`.  That is the source of the error that is being reported.

There are lots of articles on using ESM module files so I won't attempt to cover all of that here, but nodejs knows whether a file is an ESM module or a CommonJS module either from the `module` line in package.json or from the file extension and in ESM module files, you use the newer `import` syntax, not `require()`.

---

FYI, there is no point to using `await` in something like this:

```
return await client.get(`${prefix}${key}`);
```

That is functionally the same as:

```
return client.get(`${prefix}${key}`);
```

Either way, your function is returning a promise that resolves to the eventual value of `client.get()`.