# JavaScript - Top Level Await In Standard Script

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

As pointed out in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level) `await` can be used at the top level within modules, which is now a feature [supported by all major browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=top%20level%20await).

For regular scripts (that are not a module), however, all code after the async operation would need to wrapped in a function. Here is a simple example to demonstrate this using a promise:

```
function renderLayout(){

    // Simplified for demonstration

    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        setTimeout(() => {

            resolve();

        }, 1000);

    });

}

renderLayout().then(() => {

    // All code after the promise gets executed in this function

    console.log('Done!');

});
```

The issue I am facing with this approach is that it may not be desirable to have the code after the async operation execute from within a function, for instance because it introduces a new scope to that code block or allows for the use of a `return` statement.

I am currently working on a script that performs some asynchronous changes to the layout and would like the rest of the script to continue only **after** those changes have been made, as if they were executed directly in the global scope and **not from a function**.

I should also mention that this is part of a templating/preprocessing system, where the part after the async operations is dynamically generated, which is why I would prefer "standard" behavior for it.

Given that this is possible in modules, I am hoping there is a way to implement it in regular scripts as well. If anyone knows of a way to achieve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "*allows for the use of a return statement*" - uh, why would you use a `return` statement at the top-level of a script?

Comment: No, this is not possible - script execution is blocking rendering by default, and therefore must not use `await`. Why not use a real module? Or make your template system emit code in a function? Why does the code need to run in the global scope, what does it do? What are you changing about the layout, why does that need to be asynchronous?

Comment: @Bergi Exactly, it should throw an error, which it wouldn't if the dynamic code were rendered inside a function. The dynamic part of the code should just act like a regular script running at the top level, that gets inserted into my "template", i.e. the system takes a code similar to the one in the example, combines it with the necessary dynamic part and serves it as a single file.

Comment: "*The dynamic part of the code should just act like a regular script running at the top level*" - but it can't. A regular script runs immediately and blocks rendering. This is impossible if it only runs later, after the asynchronous layout animation. But what makes you think that the dynamic part actually **needs** to run like a global script? Surely it doesn't contain a `return` statement and expects that to throw a syntax error.

Comment: @Bergi You are right, it is delayed and therefore not exactly the same. And it is also true that it probably does not contain a `return` statement. However, this part is user-provided and I want to emulate the expected behavior of a standard script as closely as possible, except for the custom layout/rendering before calling it of course.

Comment: Well if you insist you can dynamically `eval` it in the global scope (or create an inline `<script>` element) when your layout is done; your templating just needs to stringify the user-provided part (or put it in a metadata script or something that won't be evaluated immediately). But I would still strongly suggest not to run the user-provided code in the global scope, and simply properly document this behaviour.

Answer (score -1):

Just wrap your entire script with async [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) thus you would "kind of" emulate the top-level `await` in modules. You could also consider to add `defer` to `script` since modules are deferred.